# When using c++ connector to connect to MYSQL, to close or to delete the con, pstmt or res variables?

Tags: c++, mysql

I am connecting to MYSQL using c++ connector, I am using a loop to get data again and again.
I am not sure if to close or delete the pstmt, con and res variables in the code below?
When do I use close and when do I use delete?

```
  sql::Connection *con;
    sql::PreparedStatement *pstmt;

    con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "password");
while(3==3)
{
    pstmt = con->prepareStatement("select * from IBF (seconds<=(?)) ");

    pstmt->setString(1,"1367822164");
    int update_count=pstmt->executeUpdate();

    res = pstmt->executeQuery();

    res->afterLast();

    while (res->previous())
    {
    cout << res->getDouble("try1") << endl;
    }

    pstmt->close();// changed to fix too many connections open
    res->close()
} 


    delete pstmt;
    delete res;
    con->close()
```

Comment: if the program will end shortly after the loop, you don't need to bother, they'll be cleaned up automatically when the program exits. If it will keep running for a while, you should clean them up.

Comment: Hi Barmar, do I need to use both ->close() and ->delete() or is it enough to use ->close()?

Comment: You need all of them. The first two are data structures holding the data returned from the API, the last disconnects from the server.

Comment: So Is it OK to write: pstmt->close();delete pstmt ;pstmt = con->prepareStatement("select * from IBF (seconds<=(?)) "); is there a problem of using the pstmt after deleting it? or when do I need to delete the pstmt?

Comment: I'm sorry, I earlier thought you were just asking about the last 3 statements, not the stuff inside the loop. I'm not so sure about the other ones.